# Original Apple clock information

Tags: apple-inc

I've been doing a clean out and I found an original Apple clock. It's over 13 years old at least and is in mint condition in a metal apple box.

I can't find it anywhere on the internet, could anyone tell me how much it is worth or more about the product? (Is it rare or limited edition?)

[image]

Comment: Is there any type of product information on the item itself or box you can include in your question?  Also why couldn't you include a better picture of the item and its box, showing it all not a cropped oversize image?

Answer (score 1):

It was a Marketing campaign by Apple in 2003, giving it for **free** for Test Drive of they Power Mac G5 called Test Drive ([G5TestDrive.ca](http://G5TestDrive.ca)), a limited edition Apple-branded stopwatch.

> Apple has sent at least some of its apple canada customers a special
>   promotion postcards in the mail.the promotion offers a g5 test drive
>   (g5testdrive.ca) along with a limited edition apple-branded stopwatch
>   (photo) as well as an entry to win a new 1.8ghz g5 powermac and a
>   20inch apple cinema display.for a limited time, apple is also offering
>   invitees a $200 discount on a g5/display/applecare bundle.again, the
>   offer is only open to direct-mail postcard recipients.

http://www.macrumors.com/mac/?sid=20040317155502